# Kendo UI cannot save property in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I made a Update `Controller` to update property and save it in Database. When I saved `isSelected` is true, in turned out `false` after clicked `Refresh` button. I didn't know what happened with my code.

```
public ActionResult UpdateSub([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel> list)
        {
            if (list != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var SubCate in list)
                {
                    var categoriToUpdate = dbContext.ProductSubcategories.First(p => p.ProductSubcategoryID == SubCate.ProductSubcategoryID);
                    TryUpdateModel(categoriToUpdate); //maybe the problem ???
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
              }
           return Json(new[] { list }.ToDataSourceResult(request));
          }
```

Any suggestions for my code. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't update an entity record like that..following is the correct way to update a record using EF

```
//get the record first
var category= dbContext.ProductSubcategories.where(p => p.ProductSubcategoryID == SubCate.ProductSubcategoryID).SingleOrDefault();

//update the catgory
category.isSelected=true;
category.Name="New Name for example";

//Mark catgory obejct as modified
 dbContext.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
//Save whole entity graph to the database
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

- if you are updating list of records i suggest make a seprate function in DAL which accepts List catList and do foreach in the list and update record one by one and then SaveChanges() on the last to execute final.
- more information on EF
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

## shaz

Comment: It worked @Shaz, but I have one question. If I want to edit `category.Name` in Grid of Kendo UI, what should I do? In your code is handy code, right?

Comment: Two ways of doing it. 1 post all data back to controller from kendo grid 2. use Ajax functionality of grid and create update function in your controller and grid will automatically call that function to update model values. take a look of this example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-inline.html